# how to convert a list to tuple , I tried based off a google search and it never worked

Tags: python

I wanted to create  a function that returns a tuple of my 5 calculations(avg,min,neg,max sum )
These 5 calculations are based off user input  and the code ends when user enters q/Q however I am having a hard time converting My list named "ListStats" into a tuple

```
user_input = ''
user_values = []
x = 0
maxim = 0
sum_in_list = 0
avg = 0
neg_values = 0
mini = 0
z = 0
tuple1 = ()
while True:
    user_input = (input('input:'))
    if user_input in ['q', 'Q']:
        break

    elif user_input not in  ['q', 'Q']:
        user_values.append(int(user_input))


for value in user_values:
    maxim = max(value,maxim)
#print( "the maximum value in the list is : " , maxim)

Minumum_value = min(user_values)
#print( "the minumum value in the list is : " , Minumum_value)

for value in user_values:
    if value < 0:
        z = len(value)
        #print('the negative values are : ' , z)
      
for value in user_values:
    sum_in_list = value + sum_in_list
#print('the sum is :' , sum_in_list)

for value in user_values:
    avg = sum_in_list / ( len(user_values))
#print('the avg is :' , avg  )

Liststats = [avg,z,maxim,sum_in_list,Minumum_value]

 

def jack(x):
    
    Liststats = [avg,z,maxim,sum_in_list,Minumum_value]

    tuple1 = tuple(Liststats)
print(tuple1)




jack(x)
```

I simply wanted to return 5 stats based off user input as a tuple , how would I convert Liststats as a tuple , how can I make a function  to return 5 stats and take refernce to my list

Comment: There are some pretty serious issues with this code. What is the point of the `jack(x)` function, exactly? It takes an input `x` and doesn't do anything with it. It also just prints a tuple (assuming the indentation was messed up when you pasted into Stack Overflow). If you want `Liststats` as a tuple, do `(avg, z, maxim, sum_in_list, Minimum_value)` instead of square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems your print statement in `jack(x)` is just not indented correctly.

```
def jack(x):

    Liststats = [avg,z,maxim,sum_in_list,Minumum_value]

    tuple1 = tuple(Liststats)
    print(tuple1)
```

Python goes off of whitespace and the `tuple1` is a local variable not global.

Perhaps also pass the list in as a parameter.

```
def jack(myList):
    return tuple(myList)
    
print(jack(Liststats))
```

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, you're overwriting the built-in `list()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty tough to follow what's going on in your code, and I can't reproduce your error since you haven't provided your input.

But calling tuple(any_list_object) should correctly give you a tuple.
It looks like your issue may come from a misunderstanding about functions.

Tl;dr your function isn't doing what you think it is

All of your code except for the jack() function will run as soon as the file is loaded. This means that tuple1 is created as an empty tuple at the beginning. This is what is printed when you try to print tuple1 (see that it is unindented, so it is not part of the function).

When you call the jack function at the end, this function makes a new variable also called tuple1 which is shadowing the earlier tuple1 (that is in the global scope). I think this is what you were intending to do, but then the function ends, and this variable goes out of scope without being used.